# How can I show any Circle on react-mapBox-gl?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geometry, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm having a hard time to show any circle on my **Mapbox**, I'm using `React` and `disease.sh API` to fetch the data.

I do not know if there is a problem on Mapbox or in my code, cause I got no error from the console. Please advice.

```js
import React from "react";
import numeral from "numeral";
import {Popup, Layer, Feature,GeoJSONLayer} from 'react-mapbox-gl';

const casesTypeColors = {
  cases: {
    hex: "#CC1034",
    multiplier: 800,
  },
  recovered: {
    hex: "#7dd71d",
    multiplier: 1200,
  },
  deaths: {
    hex: "#fb4443",
    multiplier: 2000,
  },
};



export const showDataOnMap = (data , casesType = 'cases') =>
  data.map((country) => (
    
   
    
    <Layer
      id='clusters'
      type='circle'
      paint={{ 
         'circle-radius':  Math.sqrt(country[casesType]) * casesTypeColors[casesType].multiplier,
         'circle-color': casesTypeColors[casesType].hex,
         'circle-opacity': 0.4
      }}
      coordinates={[country.countryInfo.long, country.countryInfo.lat]}
      {...console.log(Math.sqrt(country[casesType]) * casesTypeColors[casesType].multiplier)}
      >  
      
      <Feature coordinates={[country.countryInfo.long, country.countryInfo.lat]}/>
    </Layer>
  ))
```

Comment: Where do you call that function? Do you add that layer to the Map? Also, did you create a source?

Comment: yes i call it on map.js, but i didn't create a source because the data i use is from an api

Comment: Can you show us the map.js then? This function looks good for me, so perhaps the source data is not loaded or this is not added correctly to the map

Comment: yes i just posted a answer

Comment: Ok, so you don't load the source at all. Seems like you have the ```coordinates``` prop in your Layer, but it doesn't take that as a prop. Layer references the Source instead and that's where the data is coming from for that layer

Comment: ok, so i have to create a source to load the coordinates? , cauz on the mapbox gl they use <Feature coordinates={[country.countryInfo.long, country.countryInfo.lat]}/> to do that.